# Get the column value <td> from a selected row <tr> by the class Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A short question: i use a usually html + twig table which i fill with a lot values. The important part of this table looks like that:

```
{% if rec.pDsDuplicate =='0'%}
                            <td class="PFu1Exists">

                                {{rec.getPFu1Exists()}}
                            </td>
                            <td class ="PFu2Exists">
                                {{rec.getPFu2Exists()}}
                            </td>
                            <td class ="PFu3Exists">
                                {{rec.getPFu3Exists()}}
                            </td>
                            <td class= "PFu5Exists">
                                {{rec.getPFu5Exists()}}
                            </td>
                            <td class ="PSdqExists">
                                {{rec.getPSdqExists()}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="PFupExists">
                                {{rec.getPFupExists()}}
                            </td>
                        {% else %}
```

Now i use this function to select a row:

```
 $("#search_results tr").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
 });
```

after the selection, the row belongs to the class "selected".

**Now my specify question**: How i can get the value from the  column with using the class/ID Attribut e.g *PFu1Exists* from the selected row.

of course, i can iterate about the row and compare, but im looking for a quick an short JQuery line.

during reading some posts here, i found the function closest and find, but how i have to write the statement that  i can be shure!, that the query is just searching in the selected row.. ? and not will traverse up and down to the next row?

```
value= $(.selected).closest(.selected).find('.PFu1Exists');
```

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your click function, you already remove other selected classes. that means, within your table, there is only 1 `tr` that has `selected` class. So, You can just use it like :

```
$('.selected').find('.PFu1Exists');
```

by using [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), you will only search through its child / descendants. it wont find its siblings. you can read more from

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for this..

```
$("#search_results tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    alert($(this).find('.PFu1Exists').html()); 
});
```

OR you can use -

```
alert($('tr.selected').find('.PFu1Exists').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `find()` function to search inside `<tr>`.
you can directly use

`$('.selected .PFu1Exists')`

which will select the child `<td class='PFu1Exists'>` inside `<tr class='selected'>`.